# Install ICP and kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, ibm-cloud, kubernetes-helm

I have install ICP (ibm cloud private) with the Ibm [doc](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSBS6K_3.1.2/installing/install_containers.html).

And the platefom is launched on my https://:8441, so far so good. 
So i tried to launch something in the "catalogue" but the readme is empty. For every items in the catalogue.[image]

I have already tried to update the Helm repo, same issue, even in command line.
But on my server i can't connect to kubernetes.

 I'm in a proxy
When i try `kubectl cluster-info`

[image]

Am i missing something ?
Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Check if you are able to do a curl to the api-server and fetch any output

Comment: I have a 403 forbidden, it may be the proxy

Comment: So, even though if everything is working with the cluster then also it throws "403" forbidden error. Try getting any other resources like nodes, namespaces etc.

Comment: i have access to evrething except that